# How to implement a list splitter based on predicate

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement a list-splitter based on a given predicate.The functionality is a similar to a recursive break.I input in a list ,and i append elements to a small list as long as the predicate for the given element is true.When the predicate is false i append the formed list to a bigger list and i continue from where i remained ignoring the element corresponding to the false predicate.

P.S: I am trying to not use any Data.List functions only self-implemented.(I'm in learning phase).
Example:

**input** 
 predicate: `(\x->x<3)`
           list : `[1,2,3,2,3,1,1,1,3]` 
**output:**
  `[[1,2],[2],[1,1,1]]`

I have tried so far with the following approach:
I use a list that given a list it breaks it in a tuple of 2.The first element is the list until the false predicate.The second is the rest.I feed this tuple to a function that performs this again and again.

```
splt::(a->Bool)->[a]->[[a]]
    splt p []=[]
    splt p (x:xs)=go p [] (x:xs) where
                  go p rez []=rez
                  go p rez ls=rez:process . brk $  ls [] where
                  process  (x,[])=rez:x
                  process ([],x)=go p rez x


    brk::(a->Bool)->[a]-> ([a],[a])
    brk p []= ([],[])
    brk p (x:xs)=go p ([],x:xs) where 
                 go p (accu,[])= (accu,[])
                 go p (accu,x:xs)|not (p x) =(accu,xs)
                                 |otherwise = go p (x:accu,xs)
```

I get the following error : `cannot produce infinite type.`

I have also tried a simpler solution:

```
format::(a->Bool)->[a]->[[a]]
   format p []=[]
   format p ls=go p [] [] ls where
               go p small big []=small:big
               go p small big (x:xs)=case p x of 
                                     True ->go p x:small big xs
                                     False ->go p [] small:big xs
```

But it does not work and i also have to reverse the results in both cases.The error i get is:

```
* Couldn't match type `a' with `[a0]'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          wrds :: forall a. (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
        at Ex84.hs:12:5-31
      Expected type: [a0] -> Bool
        Actual type: a -> Bool
    * In the first argument of `go', namely `p'
      In the expression: go p [] []
ls
```

Comment: What is not working? What error do you get? What did you try? Why do you use `case` on a `Bool` here?

Comment: There are multiple issues including formatting of code in the question. It's not clear what you're asking about

Comment: I updated the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one is just a bracketing issue and can be remedied by correctly parenthesising the arguments as follows:

```
case p x of 
    True ->go p (x:small) big xs
    False ->go p [] (small:big) xs
```

By not doing so, the lists are being treated as functions. You will have to map reverse on the resulting list as well in this case.

You can also try using the span function for this:

```
splt :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
splt _ [] = []
splt p xs = let (xs', xs'') = span p xs
                remaining   = dropWhile (not . p) xs''
            in case xs' of
              []  -> splt p remaining
              xs' -> xs' : splt p xs''
```

Comment: By the way is my approach efficient?The second approach?

Comment: You will have to reverse all the lists inside the final list and then reverse the final list as well so I think it is less efficient.

Answer (score 2):

This is a way of implementing what you need.

What I did is to use the function `span`, that breaks the list in two, returning a tuple. The first element is the list of initial elements satisfying `p`. The second element of the tuple is the remainder of the list.

I used this recursively, while discarding the elements that do not satisfy `p`.

```
splt :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
splt p [] = []
splt p ls = let (a,rs)  = span p ls
                (b,rs') = span (not . p) rs
            in if null a then splt p rs' else a : splt p rs'
```

You can also try to define `span` yourself